# Need Alternate Code for For Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using below code in vba but it taking too much time to run. Report have 8 sheets and 450+ rows should be check in each sheet.

```
Sub forloop()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row - 1
For s = 1 To Sheets.Count
    For x = lr To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(x, 2) <> "" Then
        Cells(x, 2).EntireRow.Delete
    Next x
Next s
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Could you please suggest me any alternate method to run fast.

Comment: Does your code do what you want?  Seems like it only operates on the ActiveSheet...

Comment: @TimWilliams - i'll open required workbook and the code need to perform on that workbook

Comment: @TimWilliams - Yes, it need to run first sheet and then next sheet until last sheet

Comment: Could you just sort the sheet instead of deleting the entire row?

Comment: @saikrishna Well, as far as making it process all Sheets goes, you could change your instances of `Cells(x, 2)` to `Sheets(s).Cells(x, 2)` - but this won't help the speed. For that, you'll have to rework the row deletion, because deleting rows is *time-consuming*

Comment: @RyanWildry - No, if column 'b' value is blank it should not show in report

Comment: @saikrishna is it enough to just filter out rows where column B is blank? Do they *have* to be deleted?

Comment: Try restricting the range, and using ClearContents.

Comment: (a) Putting an `End If` into your code to match the `If` will at least allow the code to run.  Or is that a typo when you were including the code into this question?  (b) You are setting `lr` only once.  That needs to be done for each sheet.  (Unless every sheet has exactly the same number of rows.)

Comment: Is there any do while function instead of for loop ?

Comment: @YowE3K - (a) typo error  and (b) yes, all sheets have exact rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dim wb as workbook, sht as worksheet, lr as long, r as long

set wb = workbook.open(wbPathHere)

for each sht in wb.worksheets
    lr = sht.cells(sht.rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).row - 1
    for r = lr to 1 step-1
        if sht.cells(r, 2) <> "" Then sht.cells(r, 2).entirerow.delete
    next r    
next sht
```